# How do I send a list to Azure Durable Functions

Tags: python, azure, function

I have an architecture with two python functions: listcreator() and activity(). The listcreator() function is triggered by an http trigger and generates a list of strings. I want to pass this list of strings to an orchestrator function and call the activity() function multiple times.

How do I pass this to the orchestrator? Do I also need a starter function as desribed in the microsoft documents? https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

An oversimplified version of my code looks like this:

listcreator():

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse
     mylist=['helo','world']
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code what you tried and the result of error you got?

Answer (score 0):

probably the best solution is to use your `listcreator()` function as `Client function` (the function you called as `starter function`). From the `listcreator()`, you can generate the list and pass it to the `orchestrator`. Finally from the orchestrator, pass the list to the `activity` function and run it.

A sketch of code:

```
# inside the client function call the orchestrato
client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
instance_id = await client.start_new("yourorchestrator", None,  [1,2,3,4])

#inside orchestrator
data = context.get_input()
context.call_activity("activity", data)
```